# How to draw random lines in Turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

It repeats 20 times as long as the user enters yes. Has a random color. random width (between 1 and 20).  random x coordinate between -300 and 300, random y coordinate between -230 and 230.  with the pen down, go to the x and y coordinates.  Can I get a quick explanantion on how to do this
Heres my attempt(i know its wrong)

```
turtle.width(5)
def f(input):
    if input == "yes":
        if x>20:
            xc = randrange(-300, 301)
            yc = randrange(-231, 231)
            turtle.width(randrange(1,21))
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(0,0)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.color(randcolor)            
            return x-1
```

Comment: What's wrong about it or missing in it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *loop* over the line drawining code 20 times, i.e:

`for lineNo in range(20):  ...`

To draw a line segment, you require **4** points, the `(x1,y1)` of the start point, and either an angle `theta` or another point `(x2,y2)`. You are better of generating one point, then generating a random angle `a` and use the desired length of the line to calculate `(x2,y2)`.

Then, your calls `pendown()` and `penup()` cancel each other out. Goto the first point, put the pen down and then goto the endpoint.